# Проблема с Ubuntu Software

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-software

Только установил Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS, после установки не работает, но запускается Ubuntu Software, всплывала ошибка о неудовлетворенных зависимостях, интернет работает нормально. Пытался фиксить ошибку в терминале командами `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt install -f`, `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt full-upgrade`, но ничего не помогло, он так и не начал работать. Можете помочь, пожалуйста?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` и перезагрузиться попробуй.

Comment: Скриншот не слишком-то информативен. Лучше было бы привести тексты ошибок, выдаваемых вашими командами, желательно, не в виде картинки.